# Branch IO generate link show in Quick Links Dashboard

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking, branch.io, share-intent

Android Platform

i use below code to generate and share the link in Facebook etc, and click it, it has record in " Summary ", but not show in Quick Link Dashboard.

```
val lp = LinkProperties()
        .addControlParameter("\$deeplink_path","https://www.google.com")


 val buo = BranchUniversalObject()
            .setCanonicalIdentifier("item/abcd")
            .setTitle("Hellow Title")
            .setContentDescription("Hello Description")
            .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)
            .setLocalIndexMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)

buo.generateShortUrl(
            activity, lp
        ) { url, error ->
            if (error == null) {
                // share intent
            } else {
                Logger.e("error: ${error.message}")
            }
        }
```

Using the code, this cannot show in the Quick Link Dashboard.
About the doc, it need add two params "type:2" and "$marketing_title", i set it to LinkProperties:

```
lp.addControlParameter("type", "2")
.addControlParameter("\$marketing_title", "android _test")
```

Or: BranchUniversalObject:

```
buo.setContentMetadata(ContentMetadata().addCustomMetadata("type", "2"))
   .setContentMetadata(ContentMetadata().addCustomMetadata("\$marketing_title","android"))
```

But it not work, so, how to solve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your SDK-created links will not be visible on the Quick Links Dashboard. The specification of passing `type:2` and setting a `marketing title` in the request payload is limited to API-created links only.

Understanding that you'd want to check the conversions, it is highly recommended to tag these branch links (e.g. `channel = API`/`campaign=Promo`) so that you can segment your data to see all installs/clicks from links created via the SDK on the Branch Dashboard `Sources/Summary` section.